# opencv and spyder ipython console freeze

Tags: python, opencv, ipython, spyder

Using python 3.6.1, spyder 3.1.4, opencv 3.3, anaconda 4.4, windows 7.
Everything appears to work fine when I am importing and exporting using opencv. Once I start to use the display functions in opencv, everything starts to freeze.

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture('filename.h264')
(grabbed,frame) = camera.read()
cv2.imshow('viewer',frame)
```

This basic code will load up a window under the anaconda ?window? and freeze forcing a reboot of the ipython kernel. This does not happen when using the python kernel directly. I ask as spyder 3.2 removes the python kernel leaving the ipython kernel that doesn't function for me. So I was wondering why this error occurs so I can try and fix it.

Answer (score 3):

you should add

```
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

after everytime you use

```
cv2.imshow('something', frame)
```

Comment: This kind of helps... The kernel now crashes _after_ showing the image ;-)